# AWS CloudFormation ApiGatewayV2 Target property required

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I'm attempting to build a CF stack that essentially does what an AWS guide can do through the console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html

I'm able to create it manually through the console, and it works. Now I'd like to use ApiGatewayV2, because it hs the `AutoDeploy` feature, whereas the RestApi does not. My `template.yml` is (only the relevant bits):

```
  GatewayV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-GatewayV2
      Description: API Gateway for integrations
      ProtocolType: HTTP
      CredentialsArn: !GetAtt SubmitOrderResourceRole.Arn
      RouteKey: $default
  StageV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref GatewayV2
      DeploymentId: !Ref DeploymentV2
      StageName: $default
      AutoDeploy: true
  DeploymentV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - RouteV2
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref GatewayV2
      Description: Deployment for the API Gateway
  RouteV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref GatewayV2
      RouteKey: POST /orders
      Target: !Join
        - /
        - - integrations
          - !Ref IntegrationV2
  IntegrationV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref GatewayV2
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      CredentialsArn: !GetAtt SubmitOrderResourceRole.Arn
      IntegrationMethod: POST
      IntegrationUri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/StartSyncExecution
      PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
      RequestTemplates:
        application/json: !Sub |
          {
            "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
            "stateMachineArn": "${SubmitOrderStateMachine}"
          }
      ResponseParameters:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseTemplates:
            application/json: |
              if(!$input.json('$.status').toString().equals('"SUCCEEDED"'))
              set($context.responseOverride.status = 500)
              end
```

However, when I attempt to deploy this, I get an error back:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Target is a required property in this context
```

If I try to use the `Target` property of the `ApiGatewayV2` and set it to the ARN of my step function:

```
  GatewayV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-GatewayV2
      Description: API Gateway for integrations
      ProtocolType: HTTP
      CredentialsArn: !GetAtt SubmitOrderResourceRole.Arn
      RouteKey: $default
      Target: !Sub integrations/${SubmitOrderStateMachine}
```

I instead get this error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Target only supports HTTP Proxy or Lambda Proxy
```

Does anyone know why the `Target` property is required "in this context", and how I can bypass it? Its docs say it's only for the quick-create features, which I don't need to do here. I'm happy to define the specific deployments, stages, routes, and integrations to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api only supports two kinds of APIs: WebSockets and HTTPS via quick create.

The older [V1 API Gateway](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/AWS_ApiGateway.md) allows much more control over the process, and does not use quick create. You can use a Method rather than an Integration to link it to the state machine; it's complicated but possible.

I suggest creating the Gateway using the V1 definition instead (along with any deployments/stages/routes):

```
Gateway:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
      Name:  !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Gateway
      EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - REGIONAL
```

With the gateway created, you can now add a Method to link the Gateway to the Step Function:

```
GatewayMethod:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    ResourceId:
      Ref: GatewayResource
    RestApiId:
      Ref: Gateway
    ApiKeyRequired: true
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    HttpMethod: POST
    Integration:
      Type: AWS
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
      Uri: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:states:action/StartSyncExecution
      Credentials:
       ...
      RequestTemplates:
       ...
      IntegrationResponses:
     ...
    MethodResponses:
    - StatusCode: 200
```

The above was taken from https://github.com/antstackio/api-gateway-to-synchronous-step-function which is a more in-depth explanation. The [article](https://dev.to/aws-builders/api-gateway-rest-api-step-functions-direct-integration-aws-cdk-guide-13c4) explains more but this should be enough to get you started.

This approach should allow you to create a gateway without using quick create. Note there's also a difference between V1 HTTPS and REST APIs, but both should work with a step function.

Comment: This doesn't trigger a deployment. I was hoping to be able to use the `auto_deploy` of V2, but it seems V2 doesn't really support StepFunctions. As it is, it will create the resource, but it doesn't deploy it to the defined stage. It seems to do that upon first creation, but adding a 2nd method doesn't get it deployed to the stage. Is that not possible with V1?

Comment: I got around this by setting some `DeploymentCanarySettings`, specifically I added a `StageVariableOverrides` section, with `Timestamp`, which just pulls in the `Timestamp` parameter, which must be passed on command line: `sam validate --lint && sam deploy --parameter-overrides ParameterKey=Timestamp,ParameterValue=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)`. So now it "auto deploys", by creating a new deployment and destroying the original.